# Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml' in module: In ubundu 16.04 and Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento-catalog

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template
>   file: 'Magento_Catalog::catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml' in module:
>   'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'template_0'

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'template_0'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'template_0'
#0 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Template.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#3 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Block/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit/Tab/Form.php(644): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#4 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Sm\MegaMenu\Block\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Tab\Form->_prepareForm()
#5 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_beforeToHtml()
#6 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Block/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit/Tabs.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Block/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Sm\MegaMenu\Block\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Tabs->_getTabHtml('\\Form')
#8 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(273): Sm\MegaMenu\Block\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#9 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php(760): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#10 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Controller/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit.php(182): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->createBlock('\\Sm\\MegaMenu\\Bl...')
#11 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit->execute()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/generated/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Controller/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit/Interceptor.php(26): Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#19 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Sm\MegaMenu\Controller\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Interceptor))
#21 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#23 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#25 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#27 /var/www/html/magento/magento2-2.3.0/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#28 {main}
```

Comment: You have the issue in this module app/code/Sm/MegaMenu.

Comment: what was the issues

Comment: i havn't change any things in that part

Answer (score 5):

@athhar you can simply change the code for SM_MegaMenu as detailed below.

File 1: megamenu_menuitems_edit.xml - **Remove following lines from body tag.**

```
<referenceContainer name="js">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml" name="catalog.wysiwyg.js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

File 2: Sm\MegaMenu\Block\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Tab\Form.php - **Remove code**

```
$textarea = $fieldset->addField(
        'content',
        'textarea',
        [
            'label' => __('Content'),
            'title' => __('Content'),
            'style' => 'height:14em;',
            'name'  => 'content',
            'class' => 'megamenu_content',
            'note'  => 'Content width must match the number of column pixel in the Column Number field',
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );
    $textarea->getAfterElementHtml();
    $html = $this->_blockFactory->createBlock(
        '\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button',
        '',
        [
            'data' => [
                'label' => __('WYSIWYG Editor'),
                'type' => 'button',
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'class' => 'action-wysiwyg',
                'onclick' => 'catalogWysiwygEditor.open(\'' . $this->_backendData->getUrl(
                        'catalog/product/wysiwyg'
                    ) . '\', \''.$textarea->getId(). '\')',
            ]
        ]
    )->toHtml();

    $block_js = $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('\Magento\Backend\Block\Template')
        ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml');
    $html .= $block_js->toHtml();
    $textarea->setAfterElementHtml($html);
```

**And replace it with below code**

```
$textarea = $fieldset->addField(
        'content',
        'editor',
        [
            'label' => __('Content'),
            'title' => __('Content'),
            'style' => 'height:14em;',
            'name'  => 'content',
            'class' => 'megamenu_content',
            'wysiwyg' => true,
            'config' => $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(),
            'note'  => 'Content width must match the number of column pixel in the Column Number field',
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );
```

**in same file include class *\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config* in constructor as described below**

```
protected $_wysiwygConfig;
public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
array $data = []
) {
    $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
    parent::__construct(..., $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rizwan Dhuka Thanks for suggestions. In order to make it compatible with TinyMCE4 please change the following lines in app/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Block/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit/Tab/Form.php:

```
require([
        "query",
        "tinymce",
        "Magento_UI/js/modal/modal",
```

to

```
require([
        "query",
        "wysiwygAdapter",
        "Magento_UI/js/modal/modal",
```

(replace tinymce with wysiwygAdapter around line 646)